# SQLite: Merging two tables with using ID and Hash-value, where resulting IDs are from a chosen table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, merge

## Background:

There are two defined Databases - X and Y. They look exactly the same but contain different data and most importantly, the ID in database X goes from 0 to 1000 and the ID values in database Y go from 10000 to 10500. This cannot be changed!

The table layout (columns) in the databases (it's the same in both) looks like this:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id     | hash  | more stuff ...                       |
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

ID is unique (primary key) and the hash column contains a value calculated from the other columns. The hash can be the same between different entries.

## The problem

The table from the databases needs to be merged so that there is only one entry with a specific hash, no duplicates. But the tricky part is that if there is a duplicate where entry A from database X has the same hash value as entry B from database Y, the query should always take the one from database Y (or X if that is more preferred, but the SQL query should be able to choose which on that is prioritized).

### Example:

This is an example of how two tables with entries could look like and how the result should be. In this example we prioritize table Y.

#### Database X table:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id     | hash  | more stuff ...                       |
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1      | 100   | ...                                  |
| 2      | 101   | ...                                  |
| 3      | 102   | ...                                  |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

#### Database Y table:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id     | hash  | more stuff ...                       |
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 10000  | 200   | ...                                  |
| 10001  | 201   | ...                                  |
| 10002  | 100   | ...                                  |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Note that the hash value of 100 exists in both tables! Y is prioritized and therefore entry with id = 10002 should exist in the merge, NOT id = 1. The query should therefore result in the following merge:

```
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id     | hash  | more stuff ...                       |
+--------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 2      | 101   | ...                                  |
| 3      | 102   | ...                                  |
| 10000  | 200   | ...                                  |
| 10001  | 201   | ...                                  |
| 10002  | 100   | ...                                  |
+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

## Solution Ideas:

I came up with the following query during testing (not optimized just purely to get the correct result):

```
attach database 'X.db' as d1;
attach database 'Y.db' as d2;

SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM 
   (
      SELECT *
            FROM d1.table AS c1
      UNION
      SELECT *
            FROM d2.table AS c2
   ) ORDER BY entryId DESC
) GROUP BY hashNum
```

This will actually return the result I want but it's not reliable. The result is correct because the GROUP BY implementation seems to choose the entries ordered last for the result. If entry with ID 10002 has hash value 100 and entry with ID 1 has 100 the GROUP BY syntax will either give me a result where ID 10002 or 1 exists depending on the ORDER BY statement (DESC gives entry with ID 1 and ASC gives entry with ID 10002).

This however relies on the implementation of GROUP BY. The SQL statement doesn't use any syntax to actually say from which database the result preferably should come from.

Is there a better way to make this query? SQLite doesn't support RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOIN).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all records from table Y, and those records from table X that do not have a hash in Y:

```
SELECT * FROM X WHERE hash NOT IN (SELECT hash FROM Y)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Y
```